# Tailwind css laravel mix add fonts

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix, tailwind-css

I am trying to use tailwndo css for a project in laravel and I would like to maintain the nunito font for the whole app but Tailwind has its own font set. Does anybody know how to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect the font to the project (as you usually do) and just add your font to `tailwind.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
     'sans': ['-apple-system', 'BlinkMacSystemFont', ...],
     'serif': ['Georgia', 'Cambria', ...],
     'mono': ['SFMono-Regular', 'Menlo', ...],
     'your-font': ['Your Font', ...]
    }
  }
}
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family/#app

Comment: I got this step, but it doesn't seem to work I think I am adding the fonts the wrong way. How do I add a font in laravel?

Comment: Сhoose the font-weight you want here
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Nunito?selection.family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200;0,400;0,800;0,900;1,800&sidebar.open

([Screen](https://gyazo.com/0c7155d301b4ecdf261a320c0c306656)).


Copy the code from the "embed" tab and add it to your ```head``` in your `app.blade.php`.
Then add `'nunito': ['Nunito', 'sans-serif']` in your tailwind.config

Answer (score 2):

tailwind.config.js :

```
theme: {
    extend: {
        fontFamily: {
            body: ['Rowdies']
        }
    }
  },
```

css\app.css

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rowdies:wght@300&display=swap');
```

shell:

```
npm run dev
or 
npm run watch
```

now you can use `.font-body` class in any tag that you want
for example:

```
<body class="font-body">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
```

font + body = font-body

```
fontFamily: {
            body: ['Open Sans']
        }
```

(you can change body)